# Set different Auto Increment value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want AUTO_INCREMENT field to increase by some 3088 and not 1.

Is it possible?

I [read this](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/)  but I don't want to use any Stored Procedure or function.

I need unique random record identifiers that I'll need to setup into mobile devices. I don't want someone to enter 23 as 233 or 45 as 46 in which case all can be valid serial numbers
If values are far apart then mistypes most likely will not be valid serial numbers

Comment: Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: Do you want to start auto-increment from 3088 or you want a step value as 3088? Step value means if the first id is 10 next id would be 3088 + 10 = 3098.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to verify here?

Comment: use UUID/GUID for page id's and map those to the record id (AUTO_INCREMENT column) ?

Answer (score 0):

To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

You can set system variable before insert;

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=10;
INSERT INTO myTable ....
```

Comment: but that it should increment not by 1 but by a bigger number say 503031

Answer (score 0):

You can change the auto-increment interval to any non-negative positive value.

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment = 3088;
```

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment for more details.

Keep in mind this will run you out of integers more than three thousand times faster than you would have. So you will only have at most 695,428 distinct id's in a signed INT primary key. You should use a BIGINT so you have enough range to hold more values.